# Angular library exports some unexpected classes

Tags: angular, ng-packagr

For the past few days I am trying to separate classes out of some project to make them into standalone library. After overcomming different problems I am stuck on some public_api issues. After the build I get this kind of library.d.ts file

```
export * from './public_api';
export { LoggerToken as ac } from './lib/components/logger/loger.token';
export { SomeService as ae } from './lib/services/some.service';
export { SomeModule as ah } from './lib/sub/some.module';
```

I have tried switching around the imports/exports to use/not use barrel files as I have found some info that it might cause some issues. Also tried using different angular versions (started with ng6 migrated to 7 and 8 but always same outcome)

Here is my compiler options

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../../out-tsc/lib",
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "types": [],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2018"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "annotateForClosureCompiler": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true,
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  },
```

at first I have tried using barrel exports from index.ts files but after reading that it might cause problems I reverted it and every class I want to expose is directly exported from public_api.ts

I believe that these exports are not necessary, as they are all internal classes for the lib (like i.e. the exported module in library.d.ts contains just some imports from external library and on top of that they are conflicting with some other library throwing errors after I try using my library in project with --aot(-prod), dev mode runs fine.

I am pretty sure that I messed something either in the compiler or exports but I am unable to find it.

Answer (score 0):

> I am pretty sure that I messed something either in the compiler or exports but I am unable to find it.

You have not made any mistakes.

```
export { LoggerToken as ac } from './lib/components/logger/loger.token';
export { SomeService as ae } from './lib/services/some.service';
export { SomeModule as ah } from './lib/sub/some.module';
```

The above are all *injectable* references.

While they are *internal* to your project. Angular needs a reference in order to define the providers. Since providers are identified by *instance* they can be given an *alias* (ac, ae, ah) and Angular can still use them.

You will find references to (ac, ae, ah) in the webpack bundles, but no one else will be using them.